# Why angularjs throw 'Illegal invocation' when using promise construction?

Tags: angularjs, promise, location

I invoke some promise function:

```
return $http.post("anyCtrl").then(location.reload);
```

After that I have thrown exception in browser console 'Illegal invocation' in angular.

If I invoke:

```
return $http.post("anyCtrl").then(function(){location.reload()});
```

Everything is good.

I expected that all of my code snippets should be working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing `location.reload` as an argument works more or less the same as reassigning it. If you reassign an object's method and it's not bound, that object's `this` will become the object that it's assigned to. For example:

```
const notlocation = {};
notlocation.reload = location.reload();
notlocation.reload(); // illegal invocation
```

You need to invoke `reload` from the `location` object. There are a couple of ways you can do this. One is to have the parentheses with the method call explicitly as you've done:

```
$http.post("anyCtrl").then(() => location.reload());
```

Another is to use the `.bind` and bind it to the object you want to invoke the method:

```
$http.post("anyCtrl").then(location.reload.bind(location));
```

Comment: Nice! Thanks for explanation!